# How to include prerequisite apps in INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python, django

I have a Django App I'm building, which we will call `foo`.

Because of the way Foo is built, it requires a number of third-party django apps to function. For example, to run `Foo` an install apps might look like:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ('prereq1',prereq2','foo')
```

In fact, for `Foo` to even be functional, `'prereq1', prereq2'` *have to be installed* in django. Now, I can add requirements to `requirements.txt` or `setup.py` to make sure the libraries are installed when someone goes to install `Foo`, but I can't figure out if there is a way to have them installed in Django itself.

The reason for this is if someone wants to use Foo, I don't want to include instructions like:

> In your `INSTALLED_APPS` add `foo` but also add `scary_looking_library_name` and `thing_you_dont_understand`.

So is it possible for an app in `INSTALLED_APPS` to somehow require or inject further apps into that list?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I agree with Daniel Roseman's answer about the [system checks framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/checks/#writing-your-own-checks) being an optimal place for these checks. The system checks framework was introduced Django 1.7.

However, assuming you have documentation, you can also document these prerequisites such as [Django REST Framework did in their installation instructions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/#installation).

You can then do something like the below in your code ([django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) used as an example):

```
try:
    from mptt.fields import TreeForeignKey
    from mptt.models import MPTTModel
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError(
        'You are using the `foo` app which requires the `django-mptt` module.'
        'Be sure to add `mptt` to your INSTALLED_APPS for `foo` to work properly.'
)
```

This is the method I have seen used in multiple applications. The onus of reading the documentation lies on the developer.

Perhaps this is an unwanted/unnecessary opinion, but the injection of dependencies into the `INSTALLED_APPS` is nothing that I feel you should be handling with your application.

I typically try to follow the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) when designing applications:

1. ***"Explicit is better than implicit."***

   - Have the developer manually enter the dependencies in `INSTALLED_APPS`
2. ***"If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea."***

   - Trying to figure out a way to inject the dependencies into the `INSTALLED_APPS` is hard to explain. If the third-party dependencies are complicated, let the developer decide.
3. ***"Simple is better than complex."***

   - It is easier to document the dependencies and require the developer to add them to the `INSTALLED_APPS`.
4. ***"There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."***

   - The common practice is to have the developer add the third party apps to the `INSTALLED_APPS` - which is why there is no obvious way to do what you want (injection).

If a developer wants to activate an app, they will. As you so eloquently stated in your example, `scary_looking_library_name` and `thing_you_dont_understand` is the responsibility of the developer to understand. Choosing to install it for developer is imposing an unnecessary security risk. Let the developer choose to use your application and initialize its dependencies.

Comment: I was hoping for a clean solution, but I think you are right. Given that only a developer would only be doing any of this stuff there is no reason they *can't* handle some basic pre-requisites.

Answer (score 6):

I think the [system check framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/checks/) would be a good place for this. You can write a check that verifies the presence of those apps in the settings and raises an error if they are not there.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to do dependency check, however i think you demand the below code to inject your desired apps into the django site.

you must put it somewhere to execute, and do a check not to re-execute when the dependencies are loaded.
also if you use it, the `'someapp' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS` will not work correctly. maybe you need to also alter it.

```
from django.apps import apps
installed_apps = [app.__name__ for app in apps.get_apps()]
new_installed_app = installed_app + ['your desired app1', 'your desired app2', ...]
apps.set_installed_apps(new_installed_apps)
```

Comment: `apps.set_installed_apps()` is a private method used by Django's test suite, and should be used with caution. It is not covered by Django's backwards compatibility policy, and is subject to change even in minor version upgrades.

Comment: @knbk, I know. and I mentioned that dependency check is preferred. But no one asked for backward compatibility. also there is nothing private in python!