# Add django package dependency to project setting installed app

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, setup.py

I write django package name example and it has dependency to other package like rest-frame work. I want
to my dependencies be added to installed app of project that using this app, [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30270334/how-to-include-prerequisite-apps-in-installed-apps),I have seen this question and answers but I want to add the dependencies to setting not make the user manually add them.
so is it possible to add them to INSTALLED_APPS ?

I have tried :

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyPackageAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'example_package'

    def ready(self):
        import importlib
        from django.apps.registry import apps

        for dependency in self.get_dependencies():
            try:
                importlib.import_module(dependency)
            except ImportError:
                pass

    def get_dependencies(self):
        # Define your package's dependencies
        dependencies = [
            'django-foo',
            'django-bar',
        ]
        return dependencies
```

but it didnt work i also try this:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyPackageAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'example'

    def ready(self):
        from django.conf import settings

        # Add your package to INSTALLED_APPS
        settings.INSTALLED_APPS.append("django-foo")
```

and in both case i add them to my `__inint__.py` file to run

Comment: Have you tried this suggestion in the linked question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30554631/530160

Comment: none of the answer worked for me.